# How can I perform a bulk rename on variable names in a .cs file?

Tags: c#

I have a .cs file that contains many variables. I want to perform a bulk rename operation on those variables - change a large set of them all at once. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: visual studio or other editors have functions for that purpose.

Comment: Rename all to what?  Are you intending to prefix them all with something new?

Comment: Rename in the sense suppose i have variable add of type integer is there i would like to change it to addition. like that first i read all variables and generate one log file and i rename corresponding those variables and again i want to give a text/log file input so that the new .cs file should have renamed variables.

Comment: While I don't think this is a great question (context and motivation would be useful) I really don't think it's that bad...

Comment: Any refactoring tool that supports Rename (which should be any refactoring tool) can do this for you.  Check out ReSharper.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a good candidate for the [Roslyn API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx), currently in Community Technology Preview. That will allow you to load the code, find all the variables (both declarations and references), change the syntax tree to include declarations and references for the renamed variables, and then save the file out again.

I wouldn't expect it to be particularly *easy* though - I'd think of non-programmatic alternatives first.

(Oh, and obviously there could be problems if it's a partial class, or if the variables aren't private...)